# is this a valid way to define an explicit function inside addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering, is this a valid way to define an explicit function inside JavaScript's `addEventListener` function so that it could be removed at any time using `removeEventListener`?

```
var somefunction;
window.addEventListener('load', somefunction = function(){
    //do something
}, false);

window.removeEventListener('load', somefunction, false);
```

In other words, is it ok to define a variable `somefunction` and then assign an anonymous function to it inside `addEventListener`, instead of defining `somefunction` outright from the get go? It seems to work in FF and Chrome, but just wanna make sure this is officially valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: "Valid" by what criteria? It works, but may not be advisable depending on how you weight the pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work. An assignment is an expression -- it assigns to the variable and also returns the value that it assigned.

Personally I think this is a confusing way to write it. If you're refer to the function by name, put the definition where you define the name, not where you use it. In particular, if you try to do this twice, you'll have a problem because each event listener will have a different function, but it has the same name.

```
window.addEventListener('event1', somefunction = function() {
    //do something
});
window.addEventListener('event2', somefunction = function() {
    //do something
});
```

Now you can only remove `event2`, because `somefunction` no longer refers to the function that was added to `event1`.

Comment: Strictly though, assignment of an anonymous function to a variable does not give the function a name, i.e. *somefunction.name* is not defined. `somefunction = function somefunction() {...}` is needed for that (but looks a bit strange). Probably better to use a function declaration for a *real* name. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So the reason `window.addEventListener('event1', var somefunction = function() {` doesn't work is because adding `var` makes it a declaration, not expression, anymore?

Comment: @RobG It doesn't matter whether the function itself has a name, but whether you can refer to the function by a name. Assigning the function to a variable does that.

Comment: @cocopuffs That's correct. Declarations are statements, not expressions. You can write `1 + (foo = 3)`, but you can't write `1 + (var foo = 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

> [Calling `removeEventListener()` with arguments that do not identify any
>   currently registered EventListener on the EventTarget has no effect.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Notes)

So as long as `removeEventListener` has say a 'click' event as an argument, any **one** eventListener registered to the 'click' event will be removed. This is evident in OP's case, therefore it is feasible according to the criteria previously mentioned.

The following Snippet demonstrates a registered eventListener added to `#target1` to listen for the 'click' event. It will be functional until `removeEventListener()` is called to remove the eventListener within 4 seconds. Notice that this particular `removeEventListener`'s arguments are:

1. the event object............: `click`
2. a named function..........: `eventLog()`
3. and it's capture boolean: `false`

The identifying argument is 'click' and the `target.event` is `#target` that allows `removeEventListener()` to identify it's target.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var eventLog;
var tgt1 = document.getElementById('target1');
var term = document.getElementById('btn');

tgt1.addEventListener('click', eventLog = function(e) {
  console.log('target1 has been clicked');
}, false);

setTimeout(function() {
  tgt1.removeEventListener('click', eventLog, false);
  eventLog('Target1 eventListener is removed');
}, 4000);

function eventLog(str) {
  console.log(str);
}
```

```css
#target1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Start clicking TARGET1 several times and you'll notice that each `click` event is firing as displayed in the console. Within 4 seconds, TARGET1's eventListener should be removed.</p>

<div id='target1'>TARGET1</div>
```